# Multiple DetailViews to Master Detail Application using Storyboards

Tags: objective-c, storyboard, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

I am trying to add a second Detail View Controller on my Master Detail Application in Storyboard mode. I'm not sure what the correct method would be to do this. I need it to be connected to the navigation controller just like the original Detail View Controller. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: What do you mean by a second one? A detail of the detail?

Comment: a second detail view controller just like the first one in storyboard. I will need to push two sets of data to my detailViewControllers and it would be ideal if I had separate detail view controllers because they will look different from one another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean to add another level of details in the context of a `UINavigationViewController` you simply need to add a push segue to the first details view controller, as shown in the [figure](http://f.cl.ly/items/1b1d0b3q1A1H1P3g221O/Screen%20Shot%202012-12-09%20at%205.49.28%20PM.png) below.

[image: A storyboard with two levels of detail]

**EDIT**

Same thing but for the iPad version. ([Full-size image](http://f.cl.ly/items/2K0n0J2R1E0s341s2d3A/Screen%20Shot%202012-12-09%20at%206.06.43%20PM.png))

[image: A storyboard with two levels of detail]

Comment: Yes i can do this for an iPhone but will it be the same way for an iPad application using the Master Detail Application ?

Comment: The iPad version of the master-detail template has a `UISplitViewController` that pushes the details in the larger section of the split view. Do you want to push more data tapping from the larger section? Just add a push segue that origins from there.

Comment: ok so just like the example above I would add a push segue to the DetailViewController that is already on there pointing to a new ViewController? Is that what you are saying? And then all I should do is add a new DetailViewController class and change the names and identifiers on storyboard, correct?

Comment: Exactly. That new controller will be pushed by the `UINavigationController` in the right side of the screen. Check my edited answer.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the screenshots, that's exactly the way I'm doing it now. Thanks for all the help! One last question, when passing data from the view controller up top in your edited image (or Master View Controller) to the detail view controller; would the best way to do this be via segue? Thanks again for all the help.

Comment: You need to intercept the segue before it's executed implementing the `prepareForSegue:sender:` method. `segue.destinationController` will give you the instance of the `UIViewController` which is about to be presented.